# extract_subdomains returns an empty array in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In previous versions of rails the extract_subdomains was working as intended but in version >4.2 it returns an empty array.

```
ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_subdomains("aalfaa.bbetaa.com", 3)
=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
-        ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_subdomains(request.host)
+        request.subdomain
```